# The difference among diffierent tags melodic images in docker hub

Tags: ros-melodic, docker

[image: Rosanswers logo]

I find in ros [dockerhub](https://hub.docker.com/_/ros), there are different images for melodic images, such as latest, melodic-ros-core-stretch,melodic-ros-base-stretch,what is the difference among those? Specifically, I want to know what the difference between core and base? What does `stretch` stand for?

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/345390/the-difference-among-diffierent-tags-melodic-images-in-docker-hub/) by [Qinsheng](https://answers.ros.org/users/32001/qinsheng/) on ROS Answers with karma: 23 on 2020-02-28

Post score: 2

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

The DockerHub image naming is as follows:

```
ros:<ROS_DISTRO>-<ros metapackage>-<OS name>
```

So for ros:melodic-ros-base-stretch:

- ROS distribution `melodic`
- ROS metapackage `ros_base`
- OS Name `stretch` (for Debian stretch), or `bionic` for Ubuntu bionic (18.04)

The content of the various packages `ros_core`, `ros_base` etc can be found on the [metapackages repository](https://github.com/ros/metapackages/):

- ros_core: https://github.com/ros/metapackages/blob/20c6fe68aaca88813fa63821d3224865f28c9a10/ros_core/package.xml
- ros_base: https://github.com/ros/metapackages/blob/20c6fe68aaca88813fa63821d3224865f28c9a10/ros_base/package.xml

As you can see `ros_base` is `ros_core` + `actionlib`, `bond_core`, `dynamic_reconfigure`, `nodelet_core`.

---

Originally posted by [marguedas](https://answers.ros.org/users/19307/marguedas/) with karma: 3606 on 2020-02-28

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 2

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [gvdhoorn](https://answers.ros.org/users/5184/gvdhoorn/) on 2020-02-29**:
Perhaps [REP 150](https://www.ros.org/reps/rep-0150.html#metapackages) would be a more canonical source of information on the metapackages.

**Comment by [marguedas](https://answers.ros.org/users/19307/marguedas/) on 2020-02-29**:
You're right, that's where the official list of repositories is defined.

In practice I tend to refer to the metapackages directly as it's the effective list and an easier place to retrieve and process (same files, to check another distro just need to change branch, machine readable).
It gets trickier with the REPs as you need to point to different sources based on the ROS disto (REP 142, REP 150 and maybe another one for Noetic) and within those reps check for verbiage like "kinetic and newer" to know what repositories are actually included.

**Comment by [trunc8](https://answers.ros.org/users/44889/trunc8/) on 2020-12-07**:
Thanks @gvdhoorn! I had been searching for differences between "osrf/ros:melodic-desktop-full" and "ros:melodic-ros-base-bionic" for a while now. The [REP 150](https://www.ros.org/reps/rep-0150.html#ros-base) reference contained the succinct answer.